# WPF DataGrid pass value from ComboBox SelectionChanged

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a DataGrid that is filled with values from one table and a TemplateColumn that holds a ComboBox that is filled from ObservableCollection (different table). This for sure is not the most elegant way to do it, but since I have no time to start from zero and start using the MVVM approach...

Let's say :
Table Dogs
&
Table Dog_breeds

The grid holds the values from the table Dogs and the ComboBox the Dog_breeds

I need to change the id_dog_breed in the Dogs table when the Selection is changed in the ComboBox so:

```
private void breed_combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
    string test = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
   //parse the value as int and somehow pass to the according row

  }
```

How can I achieve this? I believe there must be a similar question around here somewhere that has been answered a long time ago, but I failed to find it.

Answer (score 0):

don't cast it to string, cast the selected item in combo box to an object type it's ItemSource is bound to, then you should get all its properties

```
private void breed_combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
   var selectedBreed = (Dog_breed)comboBox.SelectedValue;
   //now you can access the id and pass it on 
   //assuming that the Id is property-> selectedBreed.Id
   //you should be able to access Dogs through items, I am guessing here what you structure is
   var dogs =(IEnumerable<Dog>)dataGrid.Items
   //don't know how you match them up from your question, but you should be able to find a dog
   match = dogs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.BreedName == selectedBreed.Name);
   If(match != null)
      //do your update
```

Comment: I cast it to string only so I could see the value, that's all.

Comment: when you cast it to its own type you can see EVERYTHING :) => you can operate it based on it's type, value, etc..